# $d$-dimensional Gaussian random vector pdf

Tags: statistics, proof-explanation, normal-distribution, machine-learning

I am reading this paper: https://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/~wpenny/course/bayes.pdf
On page $4$ ( point $10.4$ ), there is a statement about the pdf of $x,$ which I cannot understand. How is this equation derived? I tried to calculate it myself multiple times and got a different result. Can anyone prove it or give a source for a proof? Thanks :)

Comment: The [The Multivariate Gaussian Distribution](http://cs229.stanford.edu/section/gaussians.pdf) online document gives details which you may find useful to help you understand the derivation of the formula.

Comment: Check out some [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Normal_random_vector) of a multivariate normal vector, from which the pdf follows. A derivation of the pdf can be found [here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/Stat/StatLec21-25.pdf).